# A ruby script to run tail on a log file?

Tags: ruby

I want to write a ruby script that read from a config file that will have filenames, and then when I run the script it will take the tail of each file and output the console.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: What platform? The `tail` command is very handy for doing this and is significantly faster than opening and seeking in the files yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [File::Tail](https://github.com/flori/file-tail) gem.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke linux `tail -number_of_lines file_name` command from your ruby script and let it print on console or capture output and print it yourself (if you need to do something with these lines before you print it)

Answer (score 1):

We have a configuration file that contain a list of the log files; for example, like this:

```
---
- C:\fe\logs\front_end.log
- C:\mt\logs\middle_tier.log
- C:\be\logs\back_end.log
```

The format of the configuration file is a [yaml simple sequence](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#simple_sequence) , therefore suppose we named this file **'settings.yaml'**

The ruby script that take the tail of each file and output the console could be like this:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'file-tail'

logs = YAML::load(File.open('settings.yaml'))
threads = []

logs.each do |the_log|
  threads << Thread.new(the_log) { |log_filename|
    File.open(log_filename) do |log|
      log.extend(File::Tail)
      log.interval = 10
      log.backward(10)
      log.tail { |line| p "#{File.basename(the_log,".log")} - #{line}" }
    end
  }
end

threads.each { |the_thread| the_thread.join }
```

Note: displaying each line I wanted to prefix it with the name of the file from which it originates, ...this for me is a good option but you can edit the script to change as you like ; is the same for the tails parameters.

if [file-tail](https://github.com/flori/file-tail) is missing in your environment, follow the link as @Mark Thomas posts in his answear; i.e you need to:

```
> gem install file-tail
```

Comment: @codecompleting: I tested with success this solution on ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32] on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601].

Answer (score 0):

I found the [file-tail](https://github.com/flori/file-tail) gem to be a bit buggy. I would write to a file and it would read the entire file again instead of just thelines appended. This happened even though I had `log.backward` set to `0`. I ended up writing my own and figured that I would share it here in case any one else is looking for a Ruby alternative to the file-tail gem. You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/amboxer21/file-tail). It uses non_blocking io, so it will catch amendments to the file immediately. There is one caveat that can be easily fixed if you can program in the Ruby programming language; log.backward is hard coded to be -1.